# Examples of pywinrm python module methods

Tags: python-2.7

example on run_cmd and run_ps methods of pywinrm in python windows remort
I want example how to execute run_cmd method
I want example how to execute run_ps method
what should be written in place of "windows-host.example.com"

Answer (score 0):

```
import winrm

ps_script=""" Get-VMMServer -ComputerName "xx.xx.xx.xx" """

s=winrm.Session('xx.xx.xx.xx',auth=('username','password'))    
r=s.run_ps(ps_script)   
print r.status_code  
print r.std_out
```

This might help you